# Getting an error when running my script in a rule

Tags: vba, outlook

When my rule runs, the script below runs, and it has been working fine, but when multiple emails for that rule come through, I'm getting a

> "runtime error 9 subscript out of range message"

when I click "debug," it highlights this line:

```
sFileName = varAddress(10)
```

Here is my code in its entirety.

```
Private Function CreateDir(FldrPath As String)
    Dim Elm As Variant
    Dim CheckPath As String

    CheckPath = ""
    For Each Elm In Split(FldrPath, "\")
        CheckPath = CheckPath & Elm & "\"

        If Len(Dir(CheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir CheckPath
            Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Created"
        End If

        Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Exist"
    Next   
End Function


Sub SaveEagleView(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim strSubject As String, strExt As String
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim NextFriday As Date
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim varAddress As Variant
    Dim City As Variant
    Dim fdObj As Object
    Dim JobArea As String
    Dim JobCity As Variant
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFinalPath As String
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Dim sFileExt As String

    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim enviro As String
    NextFriday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday)
    Set myfolder = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Loop through emails in folder
    For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
        Set myitem = myfolder.Items(i)
        msgtext = myitem.Body

        'Search for Specific Text
        delimitedMessage = Replace(msgtext, "Address: ", "###")
        delimitedMessage = Replace(delimitedMessage, ",", "###")
        varAddress = Split(delimitedMessage, "###")

        'Assign the job address from email to variable
        sFileName = varAddress(10)
        JobCity = LTrim(varAddress(11))
        On Error Resume Next

        'Define office area based on job city

        If JobCity = "Panama City" Or JobCity = "Mexico Beach" Or JobCity = "Panama City Beach" Or JobCity = "Lynn Haven" Or JobCity = "Port Saint Joe" Then
            JobArea = "Panama"
        ElseIf JobCity = "Daytona Beach" Or JobCity = "Port Orange" Or JobCity = "Deltona" Or JobCity = "Ormond Beach" Or JobCity = "Deland" Then
            JobArea = "Daytona"
        ElseIf JobCity = "Orlando" Then
            JobArea = "Orlando"
        ElseIf JobCity = "Jacksonville" Or JobCity = "Jacksonville Beach" Then
            JobArea = "Jacksonville"
        Else
            JobArea = JobCity
        End If

        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            saveFolder = "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\EagleView\" & Format$(NextFriday, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "\" & JobArea & "\"

            CreateDir saveFolder
            If Right(objAtt.FileName, 3) = "PDF" Then
                sFileExt = ".pdf"
                File = saveFolder & sFileName & sFileExt
                objAtt.SaveAsFile File
            End If

            With objMsg
                .To = "Careers@Email.com"
                .CC = "CustomerService@Email.com"
                .Subject = "New EagleView Needs Uploaded"
                .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                .Body = "A new EagleView has been received for the " & JobArea & " office. The file name is " & sFileName & " and needs to be uploaded. Thanks!"
                .Send
            End With

            Set objMsg = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
        Next
    Next

    Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit to add more info:

The subject of the email is this:

> FW: EagleView Report 26103101 - 123 Apple Ln, City, State  (Premium, $40.00, 4014 sq ft)

There is also this in the body of the email:

•   Report ID: 26103101 (Premium, $40.00, 4014 sq ft)
•   Address: 123 Apple Ln, City, State 32174-8768

What I need extracted into a variable is the street address, and the city, all other info is irrelevant for this rule

Comment: That error means there is no item `10` in your array `varAddress()` there are less so you cannot access item `10`. Debug your code and check the value of `delimitedMessage` which cannot be split into 10 items. • Additionally you should remove all `On Error Resume Next` this line just hides error messages but the errors still occur you just cannot see them. Therefore you cannot fix them and that results in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Ok, I had used that because in another question, someone said address was an array, and as I tested this on numerous emails, 10 was where the address I needed was located.

Would this be fixed, and the delimited code pull out what's between the "Address: " and the "," if I change "varAddress" to some generic and madeup variable name?

Comment: Ehm no?! Changing a variable name doesn't influence it's data. Please [edit] your question and give some examples for the data in `delimitedMessage`.

Comment: Ok, I added some info for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what your two `Replace()` methods do is replacing `Address:` and all commas `,` in your body with `###` so

```
• Report ID: 26103101 (Premium, $40.00, 4014 sq ft) • Address: 123 Apple Ln, City, State 32174-8768
```

becomes

```
• Report ID: 26103101 (Premium### $40.00### 4014 sq ft) • ###123 Apple Ln### City### State 32174-8768
```

And is then splitted into an array that results in

- varAddress(0): `• Report ID: 26103101 (Premium`
- varAddress(1): `$40.00`
- varAddress(2): `4014 sq ft) •`
- varAddress(3): `123 Apple Ln`
- varAddress(4): `City`
- varAddress(5): `State 32174-8768`

---

So I recommend to find `Address:` first and then split by `,`

```
delimitedMessage = Right$(msgtext, Len(msgtext) - InStr(1, msgtext, "Address: ") - 8)
varAddress = Split(delimitedMessage, ", ")
```

so this would result in the following variable values:

[image]

Comment: Thank You!  Now, I'm getting a run-time error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set and it highlights my ".To" line.  

If need be, I can create a new question to have this answered.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Mike Probably better to ask in a new question since this is a completely different issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment. It seems like you may have better luck parsing your Subject line instead of the body of the email if it always follows that same format like:

```
<something> - <street_address>, <city>, <state> (<somethingelse>)
```

Splitting the address out to an array would be:

```
FullAddress=Split(Split(Split(myitem.Subject, " - ")(1), "(")(0), ",")
```

Which you can then access different address parts like:

```
City = FullAddress(1)
```

Example:
[image]

As for your error, it means the array you are accessing doesn't have an item at index "10". It means your address isn't in the array where you think it is. When you hit this error, hit the "Debug" button and you can inspect the contents of the array in your VBE's "Locals" window to see what that array looks like.